# Using ansible with password authentication and different usernames

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

We're in the position of maintaining multiple database servers, which have one of two admin accounts, and which use password authentication.  Lets say that the two accounts are "db_admin" and "db_user".  The passwords are the same for all examples of each username, but different between the two usernames - ie the password for all hosts where the username is db_admin is "password1", and the password for all hosts where the username is db_user is "password2".

How can I run playbooks (or even ad-hoc commands) against all hosts.   I can set ansible_ssh_user in the inventory, and use -k on the command-line, but this prompts only once for the password, which will therefore be wrong for half the hosts.  I could repeat the ansible run, of course, specifying a different host group each time, but I'd like to do it in a single pass.

Aside: Please, I would much prefer key-based authentication - this is not currently an option.  I'd also like to (using Ansible, of course) edit /etc/{passwd,shadow,group} and change the username to be the same on all hosts, but that's not possible (and might break other things which rely on, for example an "scp file db_user@host", rather than "scp  db_admin@host" ).  Thirdly, I'd like to go back in time and prevent the divergence in the first place, but none of these are options yet.

Comment: [Ansible: how to run a play with hosts with different passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33155459/2947502)

Comment: Is that answer entirely relevant - the situation is somewhat different in that (if I'm reading it correctly), the ansible_ssh_user is the same in each case, and they are using key-based authentication?

Comment: Which answer you are talking about?

Comment: The one(s) to the question you linked to.  If you prefer, I'll rephrase: "is that question entirely relevant?"

Comment: Yes, I think it is relevant. It shows how you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Define the user and password in host_vars per each host or group_vars per host group.

You need to define appropriate parameters [listed here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters), i.e.:

> `ansible_user` The default ssh user name to use.
>
> `ansible_ssh_pass` The ssh password to use. ** Requires sshpass

Per guidance you should encrypt the values with [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/vault.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create a personal, non-privileged user for you or whomever runs these plays. Use the same credentials, such as configuring auth against a directory, or deploying a ssh key.

Install sudo rules so that this personal user can run commands as db_admin or db_user.

Set `become_user` in host_vars or inventory to  db_admin or db_user as appropriate. Set `ansible_user` to your personal user at a global level (playbook vars, or group_vars/all).  Set `become: True` on tasks run as the admin user.

This way, its clear who ran the play, and you do not have to change shared credentials.